# How to query data of a versioned file stored in an S3 bucket, using AWS Athena?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-athena

I have a file in an s3 bucket under a subfolder, this file has **versioning enabled** and the old data is getting overwritten whenever a new file version comes (every week I have 5 versions of the file, the next week I have new 5 versions and so on...)
I m trying to create a table in **Athena** to help me store the weekly data in 1 file locally
I tried different approaches but couldn't find a solution
here is my latest try

```
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `myDB`.`Table_name` (
  `q` STRING,
  `s` STRING,
  `s` STRING,
  `d` STRING,
  `f` STRING,
  `top` INT,
  `bottom` INT,
  
)
ROW FORMAT SERDE 'org.apache.hadoop.hive.serde2.OpenCSVSerde' WITH SERDEPROPERTIES ( 'quoteChar'='\"', 'separatorChar'=',', 'skip.header.line.count'='1') STORED AS INPUTFORMAT 'org.apache.hadoop.mapred.TextInputFormat' OUTPUTFORMAT 'org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.HiveIgnoreKeyTextOutputFormat'
LOCATION 's3://bucket/subFolder/'
TBLPROPERTIES ('has_encrypted_data'='false',
    'versioning_enabled'='true',
    'versioning_view'='all');
```

In the docs, they are saying that it is not possible to have this done on a **versioned bucket** but not a versioned file inside the bucket
 `Athena can only query the latest version of data on a versioned Amazon S3 bucket, and cannot query previous versions of the data.`
[considerations and limitations in the Docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/athena/latest/ug/creating-tables.html)

Any possible fix please?
**Note**: I don't have a version column or something like that in my file

Answer (score 3, accepted):

True. Athena can only query the latest version of the file.

If versioning is a must you can use AWS Glue to create a table that points to the previous versions of the file in S3. AWS Glue can handle versioning and create a new table for each version of the file: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/glue/latest/ug/edit-jobs-source-s3-files.html

Alternatively you can use a script to download the previous version of the file from S3 to a local directory, and then create a table in Athena using the local file as the input.